# Passing Glass Model in sitecore view rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore8.1

We have two glass views inherited from different Glass models, both working great individually.

Now, We want to insert one view into another. So I tried using the code below:

```
var model = new SitecoreContext().GetItem<IOurGlassModel>(path);
if (model != null)
{
    @Html.Sitecore().ViewRendering("/Views/path/Banner.cshtml", new { Model = model })
}
```

This ended up with below error message:

> Server Error in '/' Application.  Could not locate item containing
>   model definition. Model path: Castle.Proxies.IOurGlassModelProxy_1

Let me know if you need the full stack trace.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: can you try to use this Html.Partial("/Views/path/Banner.cshtml", model)

Comment: thanks @AhmadHarb it did worked, but is there a way to make it work with sitecore view rendering? and do understand why the above error happened?

Comment: I will post the answer, and why it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this insted:

```
@Html.Partial("/Views/path/Banner.cshtml", model)
```

The point is @Html.Sitecore().ViewRendering will re-invoke Sitecore pipelines and render your component from the begging. on the other side, using @Html.Partial will render the partial view using the same execution.

check this question for more details about the difference between the two methods: [Sitecore View Rendering and Controller Rendering Helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996267/sitecore-view-rendering-and-controller-rendering-helper)